# How to manage Form request asynchronously

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to manage a POST request from a form component in Play Framework asynchronously. In particular, I would like to use the form parameters in a handler that already returns a `Future`.

I'm aware that in order to handle the POST request, I must use an overload that gets a `MessagesRequest[AnyContent]` instance in input, e.g.:

```
def action = Action { implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.view( ... ))
}
```

In order to manage a Future, anyway, I must use the `Action.async` method, but I didn't found any overload of this method that accept in input an instance of `MessagesRequest[AnyContent]`.

I've already tried to cast the handler using a simple `Request[AnyContent]` instance, but it didn't integrate with the Play framework infrastructure in this particular case.

From [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync), it is clear that under the hood, both `Action` and `Action.async` are asynchronous in nature, and that the `Action.async` is just a helper facility to enable writing code in a non blocking way, which is exactly what I would like to achieve.

According to my understanding it would be sufficient to return a non-asynchronous result that would be wrapped in a `Future` anyway, but is there a way to return a `Future`, handling the `MessagesRequest[AnyContent]` from the Play form implementation?

Comment: You can wrap in a future 

```
def action = Action.asyc { implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent] =>
  Future{  Ok(views.html.view( ... ))}
}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the response in a `Future` like so

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def action = Action.async { implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent] =>
  Future {
    Ok(views.html.view( ... ))
  } 
}
```

Comment: The handler already returns a `Future`, the problem is that the Action.async method does not accept a `MessagesRequest[AnyContent]` in input.

Comment: Yes it does. Signature of async is `async(block: R[B] => Future[Result])` and `MessagesRequest[AnyContent]` fits `R[B]`. I have no issue running this on my local machine. Maybe edit the question with the exact error seen.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, there's the `final def async(block: R[B] => Future[Result]): Action[B] = async(parser)(block)` overload that could handle my case, but the `Action` method has this signature: `def Action: ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent]`, so it already defines the R wrapper. Am I missing something? Could you please tell me which version of the Play Framework you're using?

Comment: 2.7. It should be the same for earlier versions.

Comment: My apologies, you are right: my mistake was that I was using an `AbstractController` as base class, instead I would have to use the `MessagesAbstractController` as a base class. I will edit the question with the full explanation. Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

[Mario Galic Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894056/8620481) is the right answer to the question.

Just to add more details, my mistake was using the `AbstractController` as a base class for my controller, instead of the `MessagesAbstractController`.

The `MessagesAbstractController` class would indeed enable the following signature of the method `Action`, defined in the `MessagesBaseController` trait:

```
def Action: ActionBuilder[MessagesRequest, AnyContent]
```

instead of the one inherited from the `AbstractController`, defined in the `BaseController` trait:

```
def Action: ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent]
```

This would make possible to define a handler that receives a `MessagesRequest[AnyContent]` in input.